# delete first line from text file in Windows using sed

Tags: php, unix, sed, tail

I am working on PHP file and want to delete the first line from a text file.

Here is my code:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"sed '1d' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt\"");
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed '1d' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt'");
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'tail -n +2 $text_files_path/diffFile.txt'");
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"tail -n +2 '$text_files_path/diffFile.txt'\"");
```

But, nothing works!

Any idea please?

Comment: @Tom Fenech Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable should be double-quoted to allow shell parameter expansion.

Try this :

```
shell_exec('C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c "sed -i \"1d\" "$text_files_path"/diffFile.txt"');
```

**Note :** I added the `-i`  option that edit the file *in place*.